# android studio through spring mvc

Tags: android, mysql, spring

For android studio, I am doing a module where I have to take an image as well as all type files and store into our server. (i.e my sql I am using common backend.) Through Spring MVC, I am doing this project.  I am not able to save the file location to mysql.

We have to save only the uploaded location, but that location is our server.

I tried to take the image from mobile, but after taking the image it is not saving.  I also granted permission to externalsd.

my code is:

```
//image selection
private void selectImage() {

   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
   builder.setTitle("Choose Image Source");
   builder.setItems(new CharSequence[] { "Gallery", "Camera" },
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                   int which) {
                   switch (which) {
                       case 0:
                           Intent intent = new Intent(
                                   Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                           intent.setType("image/*");

                           Intent chooser = Intent
                                   .createChooser(
                                           intent,
                                           "Choose a Picture");
                           startActivityForResult(
                                   chooser,
                                   ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY);

                           break;

                       case 1:
                           Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                   android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                           startActivityForResult(
                                   cameraIntent,
                                   ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);

                           break;

                       default:
                           break;
                   }
               }
           });

   builder.show();
   dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: onActivityResult()  method you will get image URI?Have you added onActivityResult()? share you complete code

Comment: Actually i am using mysql database we did in desktop through spring mvc. I am doing android version but i am not able to store file to mysql through sql. like in desktop if we select upload file button it will open file to upload after that we have to set destination. Same destination i want to use in android studio.